# Install ChruBuntu on SD card or USB flash drive on Chromebook

Tags: usb, sd-card, chromebook

I have a question. Is it at all possible to install ChrUbuntu onto a SD Card or flash drive? Also is it possible to boot into a USB flash drive or SD card from a Chromebook? Could you also please explain how to do this!
Any help much appreciated!
Thanks in advance :D
NOTE: The Chromebook I'm thinking of buying is an Acer c720, so any instructions for that specific computer would be much appreciated...

Comment: im planning on getting a c720 but i need to make sure it can run ubuntu...

Comment: See http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html for dualbooting. Once you have enabled developer mode and can boot to legacy mode, you will be able to boot plain old Ubuntu from an SD card or USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

alright i solved it thanks to this answer
"See chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/10/… for dualbooting. Once you have enabled developer mode and can boot to legacy mode, you will be able to boot plain old Ubuntu from an SD card or USB drive. –  user68186 yesterday"